# How can I check if user had entered promocode?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have an android application in which u can simply enter promocode to get full version. But how to make in other activities check if it's been entered or not ? This is my code :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Browser.this);
                            alert.setTitle("Enter your promocode.");
                            final View input = LayoutInflater.from(Browser.this).inflate(R.layout.edittext, null);
                            alert.setView(input);
                            final EditText edit = (EditText) input.findViewById(R.id.edit);
                            alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    if (edit.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("TheSecretcode")) {
                                        isPremium = true;
                                    } else {
                                        isPremium = false;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            alert.show();
                            break;
```

this is the code for the second activity. I think it just didn't updated the SharedPrefs.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_view_layout);
    Uri uri = getIntent() != null ? getIntent().getData() : null;
    final SharedPreferences premiumSettings = getSharedPreferences("PREMIUM", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final boolean isPremium = premiumSettings.getBoolean("isPremium", false);
    if(isPremium) {
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        img.setImageURI(uri);
    }
    else {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageViewer.this);
        builder.setTitle("Error");
        builder.setMessage("You are not premium user. Please enter the promocode or buy the full version");
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.holo_dark_action_info);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Browser.this);
alert.setTitle("Enter your promocode.");
final View input = LayoutInflater.from(Browser.this).inflate(R.layout.edittext, null);
alert.setView(input);
final EditText edit = (EditText) input.findViewById(R.id.edit);
final SharedPreferences premiumSettings= getSharedPreferences("PREMIUM", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    SharedPreferencesEditor.Editor editor= premiumSettings.edit();
    if (edit.getText().toString() == "TheSecretCode") {
      isPremium = true;
    } else {
      isPremium = false;
    }
    editor.putBoolean("isPremium", isPremium);
    editor.commit();
  }
});
alert.show();
break;
```

Then in another Activity, retrieve your Preference :

```
final SharedPreferences premiumSettings = getSharedPreferences("PREMIUM", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // The name is the same as previously
final boolean isPremium = premiumSettings.getBoolean("isPremium", false); // false is default value
```